# Can you determine a foreground colour + opacity when mixed with a background colour?

Tags: math, colors

I'm wondering if there's a way to determine the colour and opacity of a foreground object given the following two hexadecimal colours:

1. The colour of the background
2. The colour of the foreground object mixed with the background

Furthermore, if there's a way to do it and find a big array of colour / opacity possibilities, is it possible to narrow down the possibilities until you're left with one?

Comment: It's impossible to derive *both* the color and opacity of the foreground object. But if you have one you can get the other.

Comment: What if you had several known background colours and their resulting mixtures?

Comment: That might help if you know the foreground object is a constant color and opacity.

Comment: Yeah that's the idea, the foreground object will always have the same colour + opacity.